# find key in map vs firstOrNull in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, data-structures

I have a enum class and I want to find the enum.

```
enum class Stage(val title: String) {
    ONE("one"),
    TWO("two");

    companion object {
        // 1st option
        fun fromTitle(title: String)  {
            values().firstOrNull { it.title.equals(title, true) }
        }

        // 2nd option
        private val mapByTitle = Stage.values().associateBy(Stage::title)
        fun fromTitle(title: String) = mapByTitle[title.lowercase()]
    }
}
```

which one is idiomatic options or any other?

Comment: As a matter of style, case-insensitive comparison is one of the places I always include the parameter name for readability, i.e. `it.title.equals(title, ignoreCase = true)`.

Comment: I'd say that literal boolean arguments almost always benefit from a named parameter. The classic exception being when a function takes a single boolean parameter and the name of the function makes it obvious what the boolean means, e.g. boolean setters like `setEnabled(false)`.

Comment: I think for the first option you forgot to return the value

Comment: Yeah I forgot to return value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: use the second approach.

---

Note also that in Kotlin 1.9 there will be [a new Kotlin way](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48872/Provide-modern-and-performant-replacement-for-Enum.values) to access these entries (the `entries` property instead of `values()` function). It should already be in [preview right now in 1.8.21](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-54621/Preview-of-Enum.entries-modern-and-performant-replacement-for-Enum.values).

Now as to your question, there are a few notable differences between the approaches you mention:

- using `values()` creates a new array at every invocation, so the first option creates a bunch of arrays if it's called repeatedly (this should be solved by the new Kotlin feature I mentioned)
- using `firstOrNull` is a linear search in the list of entries, whereas using a map allows constant access to the enum's value, which should be theoretically faster for big enums with lots of entries, though I wouldn't worry too much about this specific problem until measured

The first point is rather important. Even though the first approach is slightly more readable, it's also very local so it won't have to be read very often. So I'd definitely go for the second approach.

Comment: To summarise: 1st option is shorter and easier to read, but 2nd option is a lot more efficient. (And there will shortly be a 3rd option which is better than both!)

Answer (score 0):

From idiomatic side, both options are idiomatic.

But from the performance side, **the second option is more efficient** because it uses a map to store the values and allows constant time lookups (the first one allows linear time lookups)